# Error en Aplicación Auto actualizable

Tags: android

Saludos compañeros, mi aplicacion no esta en la tienda de Google, por lo que tengo este codigo para descargar un archivo .apk desde un WebService que seria la nueva versión de la app e instalarlo, pero tengo un error al momento de realizar la instalación: "Error de Analisis Se ha producido un error durante el analisis del paquete"

El archivo se descarga bien, si ejecuto el archivo desde la ubicacion de descarga "downloads" puedo instalar la app pero quiero que se instale una vez terminada la descarga desde la misma app en ejecución, gracias por sus comentarios.

```
try {
        String ruta="http:webService/app.apk";

        URL obj = new URL(ruta);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();

        File PATH = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        //File PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File archivo = new File(PATH,"archivo.apk");

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();

        //obtendremos el tamaño del archivo y lo asociaremos a una
        //variable de tipo entero
        int totalSize = con.getContentLength();
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }

        fileOutput.close();
        inputStream.close();

        //Aca el codigo que se ejecuta para proceder a instalar
        //el archivo .apk descargado
        //el archivo descarga bien y completo pero al intetar instalar
        //desde aqui me da el error de analisis del paquete
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "archivo.apk")),
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        contexto.startActivity(intent);

        texto="000";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //texto= e.toString();
        Log.v("Error ",e.toString());
        texto="0001";
    }
    return texto;
}
```

Comment: tu realizaste el .apk, cuales el minSDK y que dispositivo version usas?

Comment: Si yo hice la app, minSDK 14 max 23 lo estoy probando en mi dispositivo fisico 4.4.2

Comment: Revisa las opciones que menciono en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema no esta relacionado con el código, si realizas la descarga del .apk este debe funcionar sin problema, pero existen situaciones que provocan el error:

> "Se ha producido un problema al analizar el paquete"

y no permiten la instalación del mismo.

- Tratas de realizar la instalación en un dispositivo que no esta considerado en las APIs configuradas en el `AndroidManifest.xml`/`build.gradle` de la aplicación.
- El `versionCode` de la aplicación que tratas de instalar es menor a la que se encuentra instalada.
- Tu Dispositivo tiene varias cuentas configuradas y estas en otra sesión la cual no instalo la aplicación. Para este punto debes buscar la aplicación en Apps y eliminarla "para todos los usuarios" (Uninstall for all users).

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, voy a revisar